# How to apply color for each area in MAP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, maps

I am new to javascript, jQuery, and maps. My requirement is that I want apply different color for each area in map using their zip code. For example in India, I want to give a different color for each state. Please let me know about any idea to achieve this.

Thanks in  advance.

Comment: can you please show some code ?

Comment: In real i don't have any code. Now only i am studying. But i can not get any exact link or examples.

Comment: You can use a vector map, [**here's one for India**](http://jvectormap.com/maps/countries/india/)

Comment: Hi @adeneo.. Thanks for reply. I will go through on it..

Comment: Thanks to all Who give down vote(Discourage)..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the problem correctly,
You can use jQuery maphighlight plugin : http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/
Demo : http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_usa.html
http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_simple.html

Comment: Hi @nagesh.. Thanks.. It will help to me..

Comment: you can mark this answer as accepted if this solves your problem.